# When running on Nougat, why does the title gets cut off when using a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using the following layout and it works great on all versions except Android Nougat where the title gets cut off when fully collapsed.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/them_color"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I have tried `app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"` but it doesn't fix the issue. How can I make it work on Nougat?

Comment: Is anyone faced same issue??

Comment: This is works perfectly in Fragment but doesn't in Activity. Is Anyone has an idea what this happens only in Activity??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Issue is [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140811).

There is even better option than removing `fitsSystemWindows`, 
just add to `onCreate` `collapsingToolbarLayout.post { collapsingToolbarLayout.requestLayout() }`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this and especially the fix but please note that your post-block won't work without a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 9):

removing android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

This [Sample project](https://github.com/ashwindmk/Android-Collapsing-Toolbar-Demo) shows how to implement collapsing toolbar in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Posting `requestLayout` in a runnable didn't work for me but if you're using `AppCompatActivity` you can use `setSupportActionBar` with the toolbar which seems to work.